# Значения переменных по умолчанию в аргументах функции

Tags: python, хороший-тон, стандарт, css

Всех с пятницей! Сегодня у меня вопрос, целью которого является найти товарищей на вкус и цвет и помочь определиться с некоторыми общепринятыми нормами.

Частенько у аргументов функции должны быть значения по умолчанию, но где лучше их устанавливать лично мне не понятно. 
такой код

```
def func(a=None, b=str()):
    pass
```

выглядит вполне органично, но когда аргументов порядка десяти, то они со своими значениями не влазят в одну строку (если, например, мы берем за стандарт длину строки в 120 символов и обязуемся давать переменным интуитивно понятные названия) и приходится писать такой код

```
def func(
    a=None,
    b=str()):
    pass
```

который выглядит, согласитесь, откровенно странно.
В то же время писать что-то вроде (пример немного надуман для чистого питона, но работая с некоторыми фреймоврками так можно)

```
def func(a, b):
    if a:
        a = a
    else:
        a = None
    # и т.д. для каждого аргумента
```

тоже как-то не комильфо.
В мире программирования на питоне есть стандарт по оформлению кода, по имени pep8, но просмотрев его я не встретил ответа на свой вопрос, поэтому делитесь, пожалуйста, своими практиками и мнением все, независимо от языка, на которым вы пишите.

Comment: PEP8 об этом не говорит, потому что подразумевается следующий вариант:

    def long_function_name(
            var_one, var_two, var_three,
            var_four):
        print(var_one)

даже со значениями по умолчанию.

Comment: понял, спасибо

Answer (score 6, accepted):

берем первый попавшийся кусок из django

```
def modelform_factory(model, form=ModelForm, fields=None, exclude=None,
                      formfield_callback=None, widgets=None, localized_fields=None,
                      labels=None, help_texts=None, error_messages=None):
```

выглядит нормально, читаемо и все довольны включая pep8

если же у вас очень много аргументов и вы не хотите их все перечислят то можете сделать так:

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    attr1 = kwargs.get('attr1', None)
    attr2 = kwargs.get('attr2', 666)
```

Первый пример лучше тем, что вы сразу же понимаете какие данные ожидает функция и даете возможность IDE показывать вам подсказки.

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно!

Answer (score 4):

На самом деле в Python есть только один вкус и цвет.

Называется он [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

> #### PEP-8: Style Guide for Python Code
>
> [...]
>
> ##### Indentation
>
> Use 4 spaces per indentation level.
>
> Continuation lines should align
> wrapped elements either vertically
> using Python's implicit line joining
> inside parentheses, brackets and
> braces, or using a hanging indent.
> When using a hanging indent the
> following considerations should be
> applied; there should be no arguments
> on the first line and further
> indentation should be used to clearly
> distinguish itself as a continuation
> line.
>
> Yes:
>
> ```
> # Aligned with opening delimiter.
> foo = long_function_name(var_one, var_two,
>                          var_three, var_four)
>
> # More indentation included to distinguish this from the rest.
> def long_function_name(
>         var_one, var_two, var_three,
>         var_four):
>     print(var_one)
>
> # Hanging indents should add a level.
> foo = long_function_name(
>     var_one, var_two,
>     var_three, var_four)
> ```

Comment: если речь идет об обязательных параметрах, то понятно что мы их никуда больше не денем. ответ @LinnTroll доступно отвечает на мой вопрос.